# Service worker with range requests plugin: cannot fetch mp3 files when offline

Tags: caching, audio, service-worker, firebase-hosting, workbox

I am working on a single page PWA that needs to have all content available offline.

**Initial setup and problem:**
I used create-react-app to set up the basics, then used react-app-rewired to replace the GenerateSW plugin with the InjectManifest and do a simple precacheAndRoute of the webpack generated manifest in my service worker.

Worked like a charm, except for my mp3-files: in Safari I could not see the duration of a track and the progress bar was dead. In Chrome it was more or less okay, only problem was that it would cut off the last 1-2 seconds when playing an audio file.

**Initial solution:** In my SW configuration, I added a specific registerRoute for mp3-files that used the range request plugin as per https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av. It sort of worked, now everything works fine in both Chrome and Safari as long as I am online. When I go offline, everything except the mp3-files can be fetched from the cache.

You can see the error her: https://cgl-hunter-kids-test.firebaseapp.com/
Click on the title image to enter the site, select "Historien" in the top left menu, and then selected any of the 9 available stories. The audio player is in the top right corner.

In Chrome dev tools, I can see that it fetches the mp3 files from the Service Worker when online. I can also see that the mp3 files do exist in the precache. I have no idea why it cannot find them when offline - can anyone help?

Thank you,
Diana

My service worker configuration:

```
const COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT = '/hunterkidsCookieConsent';
const GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT      = '/hunterkidsGameData';

/* Use client claim to handle SW updates */
workbox.core.clientsClaim();

/* Activate new SW (user triggered) */
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.action === 'skipWaiting') self.skipWaiting();
});

/* Cache files from _precacheManifest (generated by InjectManifest webpack plugin) */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {event.waitUntil(clients.claim());});

/* Handle ranged quests of mp3 files */
// https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1644
// https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname.endsWith('.mp3'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: workbox.core.cacheNames.precache,
    plugins: [     
        new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({ statuses: [200] }),
        new workbox.rangeRequests.Plugin(),
      ],
  })
);

/* Special fetch requests */
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    const {
        request,
        request: {url, method},
  } = event;
  /* Game progress */
  if (url.match(GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT)) {
    if (method === 'POST') {
      /* Write data to cache */
      request.json().then(body => {
        caches.open(GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT).then(function(cache) {
          cache.put(GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT, new Response(JSON.stringify(body)));
        });
      }); 
      return new Response('{}');
    } else {
      /* Read data from cache */
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match(GAME_DATA_ENDPOINT).then(function (response) {
            return response || new Response('{}');;
          }) || new Response('{}');
          })
      );
    }
  }

  /* Cookie consent */ 
  if (url.match(COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT)) {
    if (method === 'POST') {
      /* Write data to cookie */
      request.json().then(body => {
        caches.open(COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT).then(function(cache) {
          cache.put(COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT, new Response(JSON.stringify(body)));
        });
      }); 
      return new Response('{}');
    } else {
      /* Read data from cookie */
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match(COOKIE_CONSENT_ENDPOINT).then(function (response) {
            return response || new Response('{}');;
          }) || new Response('{}');
        })
      );
    }
  }
});

/* All other requests */
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I had to add the matchOptions to the CacheFirst strategy in my registerRoute:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname.endsWith('.mp3'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: workbox.core.cacheNames.precache,
    plugins: [     
        new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({ statuses: [200] }),
        new workbox.rangeRequests.Plugin(),
      ],
    matchOptions: {
      ignoreSearch: true,
      ignoreVary: true
    }
  })
);
```

It might have been related to using Firebase for hosting, but I am not sure.