# Workbox cache not used by <img /> tag

Tags: vue.js, caching, progressive-web-apps, workbox, nuxtjs

### Setup

```
"workbox-cdn": "^5.1.4",
"nuxt": "^2.15.2"
```

### Context

My app, Pictalk, let users save and get pictograms. So basically every user has a custom set of pictograms. For now, it works only online but I want to implement offline-mode.

### Technical Details

I display all my pictograms with the html `<img .../>` tag.
Every time I load a new pictogram I do so:

```js
created(){
          if(navigator.onLine){
          caches.open('pictos').then((cache) => {
            cache.add(this.collection.path)
            .then(() => {})
            .catch((err)=> {console.log(err)})
          });
      }
  },
```

Here is a screenshot of the Cache Storage :
[image]
As we see the URL is correct and the requests are cached correctly.

### Problem

The `<img .../>` tag doesn't use the workbox cache I created.
[image]

Comment: If you add the images to the cache from your main application (i.e. app.js) Workbox wouldn't know about the cached images so is not looking for them. So you will have to configure Workbox to cache and serve files from the cache in either of the two ways: [runtime](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes?hl=en) or [precaching](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching). With Nuxt you will probably have to use a [plugin](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/workbox/) so that you can create a new Service Worker each time you build your project.

Comment: So I just added Nuxtjs PWA module to my project and have to add : ```workbox: {
      runtimeCaching: [
      {
        // Should be a regex string. Compiles into new RegExp('https://my-cdn.com/.*')
        urlPattern: 'https://my-cdn.com/.*',
        // Defaults to `NetworkFirst` if omitted
        // handler: 'NetworkFirst',
        // Defaults to `GET` if omitted
        // method: 'GET'
      }
    ]
}``` in my nuxtjs.config.js I think. I'll try that as soon as I can and post the solution here if it's successful.

Comment: Still not working :( I'm getting the same errors as before... Here is my git repo in case someone needs it ! `https://github.com/Ratatinator97/PicTalk-Frontend`

Comment: There is no Workbox configuration in your https://github.com/Ratatinator97/PicTalk-Frontend/blob/master/nuxt.config.js

Comment: Hey it's in the "dev" branch

Comment: You are having `workbox` outside `pwa` section. What happens if you correct this?

Comment: @AllanChain it's now working only with my `localhost` backend and frontend  (`localhost:3001` for the back and `localhost:3000` for the front) but not in the production configuration (I have my front at Vercel and host the back somewhere else...) As in production my fornt is at: `www.pictalk.xyz` and the back at `api.pictalk.xyz` I shouldn't have CORS issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022640/service-worker-with-range-requests-plugin-cannot-fetch-mp3-files-when-offline) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#cached-av).

Here is the files I had to modify in order to make it work :

First, my `<img/>` tags had to use the `crossorigin="anonymous"` method :

`<img class="image" style :src="path" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

Once the `<img/>` tags are more flexible with their origin we can start building our custom registered workbox route:

```js
// plugins/workboxConfig.js
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://myapi\\.somewhere\\.com/pictalk/image/.*\\.(png|jpg|jpeg)'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'pictos',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.CacheableResponsePlugin({ statuses: [200] }),
      new workbox.rangeRequests.RangeRequestsPlugin(),
    ],
    matchOptions: {
      ignoreSearch: true,
      ignoreVary: true
    }
  }),
);
```

I had to declare this file here in the `nuxtjs.config.js` :

```js
pwa: {
   workbox: {
      cachingExtensions: '@/plugins/workboxConfig.js'
   }
}
```